# Tag points on mobile different than on desktop

Tags: bug

I am currently getting pretty close to obtain Ruby golden badge and I have noticed, that points displayed next to ruby tag on my profile are different when I check it on my mobile than when I check it through desktop. The difference seems to be constant in time. I believe this is not a desired behaviour?

In case this is relevant: I happen to answer couple of question via mobile some time ago.

Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

Mobile:

[image]

Comment: I think you're running into [this issue (on MSE)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212299/tag-score-calculation-wrong-in-android-app).

Comment: @StevenV - Yep, same thing. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [Steven V](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/254973/steven-v) in the comments this is by design, as explained by [Balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212315)

> The calculation is correct, we're just displaying a different number in the app. On the website, the displayed tag score is your answer score in that tag, and you can get the value for questions by hovering your mouse over the score value. In the app, we show the combined question-and-answer score.

Comment: 1.5 years I was waiting for answer to accept. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse You have to thank the user that posted a new bug report that made me do a search and that led me to your question. The new bug report is closed as a duplicate of this one.